# Rails application cannot connect to postgres running on docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml file has the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:11.3
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    ports:
      - 5432
    volumes:
    - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
volumes:
  postgresql_data:
```

After running the command `docker-compose up` I know the database, user and password were created correctly since I can access the postgres console using `docker exec -it df01156d5fbd psql -U myuser -W` and see the databases using `\l`. The output for this was

```
myuser=# \l
                                            List of databases
      Name      |     Owner      | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |         Access privileges         
----------------+----------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------
 myuser         | myuser         | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres       | myuser         | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0      | myuser         | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/myuser                        +
                |                |          |            |            | myuser=CTc/myuser
 template1      | myuser         | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/myuser                        +
                |                |          |            |            | myuser=CTc/myuser
(4 rows)
```

However when runing `bundle exec rails s` and entering `localhost:3000` I have the following error
`FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"`

My database.yml file is the following

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV["DB_NAME] || 'myuser' %>
  encoding: utf8
  host: <%= ENV["DB_HOST"] || "127.0.0.1" %>
  port: <%= ENV["DB_PORT"] || 5432 %>
  username: <%= ENV["DB_USER"] || 'myuser' %>
  password: <%= ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] || 'mypassword' %>
  min_messages: warning
  pool: <%= Integer(ENV.fetch("DB_POOL", 5)) %>
  reaping_frequency: <%= Integer(ENV.fetch("DB_REAPING_FREQUENCY", 10)) %>
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Are you using the ENV variables? Because you have 'myuser' for the password in the database yml file.

Comment: oh, that was a mistake when writing the post. The actual user and password are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The postgres server is running inside your docker container on port 5432, but your application is running on the host machine and searches for postgres server on host at port 5432 and does not finds it hence fails.

Try mapping the ports of the conatiner and the host machine.

```
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: Thank you I think this is it. I have an error because port 5432 is already in use but I think i can solve it.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it really helped you.